# URL semantics analysis in R

Tags: r, semantics, text-analysis

I have a dataset containing various urls.

```
https://www.thetrainline.com/buytickets/combinedmatrix.aspx?Command=TimeTable
https://wwf-fb.zyngawithfriends.com/wwf-fb.a84485c126e67ea2787c.html
http://www.thetrainline.com/destinations/trains-to-london
```

I want to do a semantics analysis of the url (the keywords in the URL after the /).

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: What's "semantics analysis" in that context? Which slash? What did you try?

Comment: like in the third url, i need to extract destinations and trains to london from the url. i am not exactly very well familiar with the concepts of regular expressions.

Comment: when you say after the `/` do you mean the path of the URL?

Comment: Something like that? `gsub('^(?:[^/]*/){3}','/', 'http://www.thetrainline.com/destinations/trains-to-london')`

Comment: yes. but can it be generalised for all urls?

Comment: like i want to seperate everything after .com or .in or .net whatever be the main url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is substantially faster and more comprehensive than you're going to get doing it manually.

```
library(urltools)

URLs <- c("https://www.thetrainline.com/buytickets/combinedmatrix.aspx?Command=TimeTable",
          "https://wwf-fb.zyngawithfriends.com/wwf-fb.a84485c126e67ea2787c.html",
          "https:/test.com/thing.php?a=1&b=2",
          "http://www.thetrainline.com/destinations/trains-to-london")

url_parse(URLs)

##   scheme                      domain port                             path         parameter fragment
## 1  https        www.thetrainline.com        buytickets/combinedmatrix.aspx command=timetable         
## 2  https wwf-fb.zyngawithfriends.com      wwf-fb.a84485c126e67ea2787c.html                           
## 3                              https                    test.com/thing.php           a=1&b=2         
## 4   http        www.thetrainline.com         destinations/trains-to-london
```

Comment: What if we have irregular malicious URLs? i.e.    (http://.https://www.something-bad.com/something/whatever.com/https://www.somethingelse.org/)Will it still recognise the different parts? (domain, path, etc.)

Comment: Also, your 3rd URL is not parsed correctly...is it?...Oh, you forgot a `/`

Comment: If you try and parse this: `url2 <- c('http://https://gallery46.co.il/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/cj/1.html?http://www.freefilefillableforms.com
+ ')` it will fail.

Comment: @Sotos because it's an invalid url. Pull requests are welcome.

Comment: I did come across actual online phishing sites that do use the "https://" in their domain - I have 251 such cases in my dataset- so as to confuse users. It is a great package, but could be updated to include invalid-like URLs.

Comment: the behavior you'd like for invalid URLs shld be…? the pkg works with https URLs. try `httr::parse_url`, too.

Comment: Will do. Monday when I' m back at work I will try it with my "invalids" and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
URLs1 <- c('http://www.thetrainline.com/destinations/trains-to-london', 'https://wwf-fb.zyngawithfriends.com/wwf-fb.a84485c126e67ea2787c.html', 'https://www.thetrainline.com/buytickets/combinedmatrix.aspx?Command=TimeTable')
> gsub('^(?:[^/]*/){3}','/', URLs1)
[1] "/destinations/trains-to-london"                    "/wwf-fb.a84485c126e67ea2787c.html"                
[3] "/buytickets/combinedmatrix.aspx?Command=TimeTable"
>
```

Comment: thanks. i am lacking in the knowledge of regular expressions